# GeoServer Could not locate a layer or layer group with id

Tags: geoserver

Caused by:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate a layer or layer
> group with id LayerInfoImpl-6f53f56c:18a6bc43dfd:79d4 within GeoServer
> configuration, the GWC configuration seems to be out of synch at  org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getPublishedInfo(GeoServerTileLayer.java:367)

How can I solve this error?

Comment: quickest and easiest is to restore your data directory from the latest backup